# django hide all form errors

Tags: django, forms

Is there a way to hide all form error messages from the user? I display my own messages and the fact that the error messages are displayed in between the form fields is of no use to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can render the template yourself, and just leave out the errors. See the docs on [customizing the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template) for more info.

Alternatively, the default is for errors to be included in an unordered list, for example:

```
<ul class="errorlist">
    <li>Sender is required.</li>
</ul>
```

So you could hide the `errorlist` class with CSS.

```
ul.errorlist {display:none;}
```

A third option would be to [customize the error list format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format), but I think the first two options are easier.

Comment: You should be rendering the form manually for almost all uses other than the most trivial.